# quiz in javascript score not showing

Tags: javascript, html

I my trying to  make multiple choice quiz but for some reason when i click on the sumbit button at the end of the quiz nothing is appearing in the score input. Ive tried everything and still cant get it to work. Could someone please explain what im doing wrong? thanks

```
function checkAnswer() {
    var correct = 0;
    var q1 = document.quiz.q1.value;
    var q2 = document.quiz.q2.value;
    var q3 = document.quiz.q1.value;
    var q4 = document.quiz.q4.value;

 var answers["Cascading Style Sheets","Dynamic HTML","Netscape","Common Gateway Interface"];
    if (q1 === answers[0]) {
        correct++
    }

    if (q2 === answers[1]) {
        correct++
    }

    if (q3 === answers[2]) {
        correct++
    }

    if (q4 === answers[3]) {
        correct++
    }

    var score = Math.round(correct / 4 * 100)

    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3>Web Design Quiz</h3>

<form id="quiz" name="quiz">
  <p> What does CSS stand for? </p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Colorful Style Symbols">Colorful Style Symbols</li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Cascading Style Sheets">Cascading Style Sheets</li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Computer Style Symbols">Computer Style Symbols</li>
  </ul>

  2.
  <p>What does DHTML stand for?</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="q2" value="Dramatic HTML">Dramatic HTML</li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="q2" value="Design HTML">Design HTML</li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="q2" value="Dynamic HTML">Dynamic HTML</li>
  </ul>
  3.
  <p>Who created Javascript?</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="q3" value="Microsoft">Microsoft</li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="q3" value="Netscape">Netscape</li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="q3" value="Sun Micro Systems">Sun Micro Systems</li>
  </ul>
  4.
  <p> What does CGI stand for?</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="q4" value="Cascading Gate Interaction">Cascading Gate Interaction</li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="q4" value="Common GIF Interface">Common GIF Interface</li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="q4" value="Common Gateway Interface">Common Gateway Interface</li>
  </ul>

  <button type="button" onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit </button>
  <input type="reset" value="Clear answers">




   <p>
Score = <input type=text size=15 id="score" name="percentage"><br>

</p>
        <br>
```

Comment: Post the HTML and JS in a [mcve]

Comment: Dunno if typo, but you have an extra space between q4 and .value, that would cause an exception. I see the edit, potentially disregard.

Comment: @DouglasDeTellem — Spaces are allowed between variable names as the start of a dot accessor: http://jsbin.com/nuxuko/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I would think this would actually submit the form, add `type="button"` to your `<button>` to prevent this.  `id` must be unique, you have 2 the same (`score`)

Comment: Multiple elements having same id's. That's not correct. Give different id to score and try again

Comment: You can also try `document.querySelector('p#score').innerHTML = Math.round(correct / 4 * 100)`

Answer (score 2):

Open the Developer Tools in your browser. Look at the Console.

You will see a ReferenceError because `answers` hasn't been defined anywhere.

---

Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). You have two elements with the same ID.

You seem to be trying to set the `innerHTML` of a paragraph, but when browsers attempt to recover from your error, they will take the *first* element with that ID, which is an `<input>`.

---

You are triggering the JS when a submit button is clicked. As soon as the JS finished, the form will submit an a new page will be loaded.

Use a `type="button"`.

Comment: hi thanks for the help , i have made the changes as in the edit above but am still not getting anything for some reason..

Comment: @BlazeRecordings — Now you're trying to set the `innerHTML` of an input. Inputs don't have `innerHTML`, they are void elements.

Comment: @BlazeRecordings — And you have a syntax error in your array declaration. You forgot the assignment operator.

Comment: so should i use .value?

Comment: Yes. (Well. You shouldn't be using an input to display output, but if you insist, then yes).

Answer (score -1):

When setting the value of an `input`-element you should use the value attribute of the element, rather than the innerHTML.

`document.getElementById("score").value = score;`

*Edit*
It is unclear whether you want to set the score in the paragraph element or in the input element, which both share the same id.

Comment: `at the end of the quiz nothing is appearing in the score input.`

Comment: hi thanks for the help i need it in the input element. I have deleted the paragraph element but its still not working for some reason

Answer (score -1):

You have a lot of mistake in your code. Which were mention before in comments. Here's solution:

```
<h3>Web Design Quiz</h3>
<form id="quiz" name="quiz">
  <p> What does CSS stand for? </p>
    <ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
      <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Colorful Style  Symbols">Colorful Style Symbols</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Cascading Style Sheets">Cascading Style Sheets</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Computer Style Symbols">Computer Style Symbols</li>
</ul>

2. <p>What does DHTML stand for?</p>
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
    <li><input type="radio"  name="q2" value="Dramatic HTML">Dramatic HTML</li>
    <li><input type="radio"  name="q2" value="Design HTML">Design HTML</li>
    <li><input type="radio"  name="q2" value="Dynamic HTML">Dynamic HTML</li>
</ul>
3. <p>Who created Javascript?</p>
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Microsoft">Microsoft</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Netscape">Netscape</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Sun Micro Systems">Sun Micro Systems</li>
</ul>
4.<p> What does CGI stand for?</p>
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
    <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Cascading Gate Interaction">Cascading Gate Interaction</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Common GIF Interface">Common GIF Interface</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Common Gateway Interface">Common Gateway Interface</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" onclick='checkAnswer()'>check </input>
<input type="reset" value="Clear answers">
```

And in your js file

```
var answers = ["Cascading Style Sheets","Dynamic HTML","Netscape","Common Gateway Interface"];
```